# Send Multiple SOAP XML requests

Tags: xml, soap

I want to initiate multiple requests while reading the MSISDN value from a file.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:saf="http://www.xyz.com/SAFSubscriberProvision/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <saf:ModifySubscriberInfo MSISDN="353123456789">

<AttributeList Value="ACTIVE" Name="STATUS"/>


   </saf:ModifySubscriberInfo>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The webservice is http://10.10.10.5:9887/axis/safsp

Currently Im using SOAPUI to manually input the MSISDN value. How can I read the value from a single column csv/txt file?

Comment: What platform? Java? What problem are you having? Do you simply not know how to read a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Data driven testing is described here:
http://www.soapui.org/Data-Driven-Testing/functional-tests.html

Short description:
- Create a "DataSource" test step and configure its source as CSV.
- Define a property, e.g. `MSISDN`.
- Use this property in the request.
- Define a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible even without SOAP UI

I wanted to provision 200K+ msisdns. I went "for cycle and wget" way. (guess curl could be used as well).

One way is to create xml (with loop) per every msisdn and then run a loop

```
for i in `ls <dir_with_xml>/`; do wget -S --debug --header="Content-Type: text/xml" --post-file=<dir_with_xml>/$i "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:XXXXX/....wsdl"; done
```

Another way are dynamically generated xml files where the msisdn would be variable taken from a file. Better if you have many numbers to treat (like 200K+).

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Data Generator as DataSource by providing the range of MSISDNs. Yo need not have to prepare the CSV or Excel etc. The Data Generator will generate and load all the 200K MSISDNs.